# Replace or Switch Counter with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, replace, switch-statement

I'm working in a controlled environment where I don't have access to edit original dev files, and can only attempt overwrites. I am extremely unskilled with JavaScript, but I would like to attempt to switch an output display on page load.

We have a progress tracking feature based on met conditions (ie, "viewed", "completed", "passed" etc). The output reads as simple text "Progress: 1/3". I would like to switch these values, and have been attempting to do so with simple unicode:

```html
<li>
    <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 0/2</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 1/2</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 2/2</span>
</li>
```

I am not sure what the best JS solution would be. I've tried replace, with singular success:

```js
function strReplace(){
  // Variables
  var myStr = 'Progress: 0/2';
  var newStr = myStr.replace(/Progress: 0\/2/g, "☆☆");

  // Insert modified string in paragraph
  document.getElementsByClassName("completionstatus")[0].innerHTML = newStr;
  }

  // Load
  window.onload = function() {
    strReplace();
};
```

but it seems like there should be a more effective solution. Here's my sad attempt with switch:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text;
  var switchDisplay = document.getElementsByClassName("completionstatus")[0].innerHTML = text;

  switch(switchDisplay) {
    case "Progress: 0/2":
      text = "☆☆";
    break;
    case "Progress: 1/2":
      text = "★☆";
    break;
    case "Progress: 2/2":
      text = "★★";
    break;
    default:
    text = "error";
  }

  window.onload = function() {
    myFunction();
  }
};
```

which is wrong on all sorts of levels, including my lack of variables.

Any ideas on how I can approach this? Is an if statement better? I am sure there's a smarter solution that what I'm attempting, but I'm fine manually adding cases for all possible progress ratios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is actually fine, if you have just these 3 cases there is no need for a more dynamic solution.

Anyways, here is a more dynamic solution which would works also with 3/4, 5/5 ....

The idea is to extract the first and second number (`n` and `k`) and print `n` black stars and `k-n` white stars.

```js
Array.from (document.getElementsByClassName ('completionstatus')).forEach ( (x) => {
  [n, k] = x.innerHTML.replace ('Progress: ', '').split ('/');
  text = '';
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++) text += '★';
  for (let i=0; i<k-n; i++) text += '☆';
  
  x.innerHTML = text;
});
```

```html
<li>
    <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 0/2</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 1/2</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 2/2</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is fantastic because, yes, there are more combinations, and can often dynamically change. Thank you for this solution - it works awesome - although I'm all thumbs understanding it all.

Answer (score 1):

I did a working example to you:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var text;
  
  // Iterate all elements and replace with stars
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("completionstatus")).forEach(
    function(elm, index, array) {
           if (elm.innerHTML === "Progress: 0/2") elm.innerHTML= "☆☆";
      else if (elm.innerHTML === "Progress: 1/2") elm.innerHTML= "★☆";
      else if (elm.innerHTML === "Progress: 2/2") elm.innerHTML= "★★";
    }
  );
}

window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();
}
```

```html
<li>
    <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 0/2</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 1/2</span>
</li>
<li>
    <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 2/2</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the working example! I implemented yours first, and it was a breeze.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

the idea of your code is perfect, but it fails because you are setting adding the text value before ad a value to it, I do an example with some changes:

1. I put the stars in an array because in this way I can access the stars more easy,
2. I iterate the elements with the class of the ul with a forEach, but since `getElementByClassName` return an HTMLCollection (not an array) before I iterate the elements, is necessary add the nodeElements to an array, and I do that with the spread operator
3. I use innerText instead of innerHTML because is more performant (in this case the difference isn't important but just in case)

I set an example with the error just to see that all function as you expected.

```js
 function replaceText() {
        const stars = ["☆☆", "★☆", "★★"];
        const completionStatusElements = document.getElementsByClassName("completionstatus");

        [...completionStatusElements].forEach((el) => {
          let elementText = el.innerText;

          if (elementText === "Progress: 0/2") el.innerText = stars[0];
          else if (elementText === "Progress: 1/2") el.innerText = stars[1];
          else if (elementText === "Progress: 2/2") el.innerText = stars[2];
          else el.innerText = "error";
        });
      }
```

```html
<li>
      <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 0/2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 1/2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="completionstatus">Progress: 2/2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="completionstatus">Progress:sdf 2/2</span>
    </li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Oscar!  Your answer was the most helpful in terms of learning; I'm really at a loss with scripting, and am immensely grateful for your thoroughness.